# How to resolve mypy error with sqlalchemy enum?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

mypy reports an error in the following code:

```
import enum
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum

Base = declarative_base()

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    col = Column(Enum(MyEnum), nullable=False)

c = MyTable(col=MyEnum.A)
```

Following is the error:

> a.py:16: error: Incompatible type for "col" of "MyTable" (got
> "MyEnum", expected "str")

How do I make this error go away without adding a "type: ignore" ? I could also replace MyEnum.A with MyEnum.A.name to make the error go away. But this doesn't look clean and is also not suggested in sqlalchemy documentation.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on my setup. When using your example in a fresh virtualenv, I get this error: `error: Variable "Base" is not valid as a type`. Did you bypass this error somehow? Could you explicit the versions of Python, `mypy`, `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy-stubs` you're using?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what exactly makes this error go away but on my setup after some refactoring and `mypy` configuring this error disappeared.

I installed `sqlalchemy-stubs`

```sh
pip install sqlalchemy-stubs
```

and created setup.cfg file:

```
[mypy]
files = **/*.py
plugins =
  sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin
```

```
import enum

from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    """My enum."""

    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2


class MyTable(Base):
    """My table."""

    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    col = Column(Enum(MyEnum), nullable=False)


table = MyTable(col=MyEnum.ONE)
```

Comment: Thank you! One minor thing though, is that currently the setup is a bit different (plugin name is now sqlmypy). See https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs

Comment: It worked for me without specifying the plugin

Answer (score 4):

You have to introduce them yourself in your script. The dynamically created `Base` class is of type `DeclarativeMeta`. If you type annotate the variable Base, mypy does not show the error any more.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api import DeclarativeMeta
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()
```

Now the Base variable is properly type annotated. I think that the DeclarativeMeta class is not to be exposed in the API, so I'm not sure how sustainable this solution will be.

Comment: sqlalchemy has first-party mypy support as an optional install via `pip install sqlalchemy[mypy]` since version 1.4

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the base class:

SQLAlchemy <v2:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api import DeclarativeMeta
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()
```

see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html

Or SQLAlchemy v2+:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#mapped-class-essential-components

NB the first method also works for v2, but the latter is probably preferable, and certainly easier to understand as it follows Python's normal inheritance system..